# I have issue in creating a module in Angular

Tags: angularjs

I have issue in creating a module in Angular, Below I have given my code, but I did not get the correct result from it.

```
<div ng-app="sc" ng-controller="tr">
{{ fruit + " " + drink }}
</div>

<script>
var app = angular.module("sc", []);
app.Controller("tr", function($scope) {
    $scope.fruit = "Orange";
    $scope.drink = "Juice";
});
</script>
```

Here is the live code link https://jsfiddle.net/hL1pacj8/

Comment: [AngularJS](https://angularjs.org/) and [Angular](https://angular.io/) are two separate frameworks. Please be careful when tagging your questions.

Comment: hi @HereticMonkey thank you for much for your explanation, I have learned one thing from you. thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have a simple mistake, it should be **`controller`** not **`Controller`**

```
app.controller("tr", function($scope) {
```

[`WORKING FIDDLE`](https://jsfiddle.net/hL1pacj8/)

Comment: @saneetharan, angular is case sensitive while coding ?